# Function returns only the first value of the input variable

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, .net-core, .net-5

I have a problem with the variable result. I have a function that asks for the input number. It returns the first input of the AskForNumber function. Can anyone help me, please? I'm new in C# and don't know many details I should. I hope for your help:))

that's the main function

```
static void Main() {
    string playersNum = AskForNumber(numberLength);
    Console.WriteLine(playersNum);
}
```

that's the function that asks for the number

```
static string AskForNumber(int numberLength) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Write number of Length {numberLength}");
    string number_string = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!CheckCondition(numberLength, number_string)) {
        AskForNumber(numberLength);
    }
    return number_string;       
}
```

then the number should be checked in the CheckCondition function and return whether its true or false

```
static bool CheckCondition(int length, string number_string) {

    if (!int.TryParse(number_string, out int number)) {
        Console.WriteLine("thats nan!!");
        return false;

    } else if (number_string.Length != length) {
        Console.WriteLine($"number's length must be {length} digits");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

depends on that it should return the number in the variable only when it's true

that's the result of the terminal

```
Write number of the length 4
qwerty
Thats nan!
1234

qwerty (Thats the result of the Console.WriteLine(playersNum); in the main function)
```

Comment: In your `Main` method, you call the `AskForNumber` method, and pass through a `numberLength` value, but `numberLength` doesn't exist yet...? Your code will not run as presented. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Jonathan it was initialized before, I just haven't attached it. The answer was solved below but thank you too:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are calling `AskForNumber()` recusively.

In `Main` you are calling `AskForNumber()` for the first time and enter "querty". Then the `CheckCondition` method returns false because it is not a number and you are calling `AskForNumber()` again. Then you enter "1234" for which the `CheckCondition` returns true and therefore "1234" is retuned **by the second time** `AskForNumber()` is called. "1234" is returned to the first time `AskForNumber()` is called where you don't do anything with the returned value, just leave the `if` block and return the value which is stored in `number_string`. But because you did not assign the return value of the second call to `AskForNumber()` to this variable it still contains "qwerty" and therefore the `Main` receives "qwerty" and prints it.

Just change your code to

```cs
static string AskForNumber(int numberLength) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Write number of Length {numberLength}");
    string number_string = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!CheckCondition(numberLength, number_string)) {
        return AskForNumber(numberLength); // Return statement added here
    }
    return number_string;       
}
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I've never ran into this type of problem:) By the way you wrote that I do nothing with the returned value but is there a way to delete the returned value or I just always should use the way you explained right now?

Comment: The return value is "Deleted" automatically when it goes out of scope and there are no more references to it. It generally isn't something you need to worry about.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either return the value then call the method or call the method while returning the value.

```
static string AskForNumber(int numberLength) {
Console.WriteLine($"Write number of Length {numberLength}");
string number_string = Console.ReadLine();

if (!CheckCondition(numberLength, number_string)) {
    return AskForNumber(numberLength); /* this will call the method in a return statement 
}
return number_string;       
}
```